# Docker multistage doesn't call entrypoint

Tags: docker, grails, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a grails app running in Docker, and I was trying to add the Apache Derby server to run in the same image using Docker multi stage. But when I add Derby, then the grails app doesn't run.

So I started with this:

```
$ cat build/docker/Dockerfile
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk:13.0.3
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME ["/AppData/derby"]
WORKDIR /app
COPY holder-0.1.jar application.jar
COPY app-entrypoint.sh app-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x app-entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix app-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/app-entrypoint.sh"]
```

So far, so good this starts off grails as a web server, and I can connect to the web app. But then I added Derby....

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk:13.0.3
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME ["/AppData/derby"]
WORKDIR /app
COPY holder-0.1.jar application.jar
COPY app-entrypoint.sh app-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x app-entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix app-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/app-entrypoint.sh"]
FROM datagrip/derby-server
WORKDIR /derby
```

Now when I start the container, Derby runs, but the grails app doesn't run at all. This is obvious from what is printed on the terminal, but I also logged in and did a `ps aux` to verify it.

Now I suppose I could look into creating my own startup script to start the Derby server, although this would seem to violate the independence of the two images' configurations.

Other people might say, I should use two containers, but I was  hoping to keep it simple, derby is a very simple database, I don't feel the need for this complexity here.

Am I just trying to push the concept of multi stage docker containers too far?

Is it actually normal at all for docker containers to have more than one process start up? Will I have to fudge it and come up with my own entry point that starts Derby server in the background before starting grails in the foreground? Or is this all just wrong, and I really should be using multiple containers?

Comment: When you have a second `FROM` line, it discards everything before it and starts a brand new image; you need to `COPY --from=` the first image for files to appear there, and you need to reset metadata like the default `CMD` to run.  Two containers is the way to go here – a container almost always starts one and only one process.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine for Docker to have multiple processes in one container but the concept is different: one container, one process. Having a database separately is certainly how it should be done.

Now the problem with your Dockerfile is that after you've declared a second `FROM`, you have effectively discarded most of what you've done so far. You may use a previous stage to copy some files from it (this is normally used to build some binaries) but Docker will not do that for you, unless you explicitly define what to copy. Thus your actual entrypoint is the one declared in `datagrip/derby-server` image.

I suggest you get started with `docker-compose`. It's a nice tool to run several containers without complications. With a file like this:

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .

  database:
    image: datagrip/derby-server
```

docker-compose will build an image for the app (if the Dockefile is in the same directory but this can be customised) and start a database as well. The database can be access from the application container as just 'database' (it is a resolvable name). See [this reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) for more options.